# How to use sed/perl to find only 2d arrays and replace text?

Tags: regex, perl, sed

Currently I have tons of code that looks like this:

```
static double    testVar1          [2][8]  = {0.0}    ;  /* This is for testing var 1 */
static double    var_test2         [3][2]  = {0.0}    ;  /* This is for testing var 2 */
static double    var_test3         [4]     = {0.0}    ;  /* This is for testing var 3 */
```

2d arrays in c++ initialize with double curly brackets, so I need to only find the 2d arrays and change it like this:

```
static double    testVar1          [2][8]  = {{0.0}}  ;  /* This is for testing var 1 */
static double    var_test2         [3][2]  = {{0.0}}  ;  /* This is for testing var 2 */
static double    var_test3         [4]     = {0.0}    ;  /* This is for testing var 3 */
```

I have been trying with sed to use groupings, but I can't figure out how to escape the brackets, some posts suggest not escaping at all. I have also tried without extended regular expressions.

Just now, I found out only 9 groupings in sed are possible, so now completely stuck. Any suggestions?

```
sed -i -r 's/(.*)(\[)([0-9]+)(\])(\[)([0-9]+)(\])(.*)(\{)(0.0)(\})(.*)/echo "\1\2\3"/ge'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `sed` attempt with the regex wrinkles ironed out.

```
sed -i -r 's/(.*\[[0-9]+\]\[[0-9]+\].*)(\{0.0\})(.*)/\1{\2}\3/'
```

You had significant amounts of unmotivated additional grouping parentheses so `\1\2\3` would only refer to the very beginning of the match.  I simply took them out.  Remember, the captures are ordered from left to right, so the first left parenthesis creates group `\1`, the second captures into `\2`, etc.

The GNU `sed` extension `/e` allows you to invoke the shell on the replacement string but in this case this added no value and introduced significant additional possible errors, so taking it out was a no-brainer.  The `/g` option would make sense if you expected multiple matches per line, but your example shows no examples of input lines with multiple matches, and the entire script would need to be rather more complex in order to support that, so I took that out as well.

Depending on the language you are attempting to process and the regularity of the files, you might want to permit whitespace between the closing and opening square brackets, or not; and the "anything" wildcard between the closing square bracket and the opening curly bracket looks somewhat prone to false positives (matching where you don't want it to) -- maybe change it to only permit whitespace and and equals sign, like `[ =]*` instead of `.*`

Comment: Thank you!! Great explanations and I cleaned up my other sed commands with unnecessary options. This command worked for me and I tweaked it around a bit to fit my needs. Yes, I had so many unnecessary groupings, after seeing your example, it's so easy to understand. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Use a perl script with the following regex:

```
\w+\s*(?:\[\d+\]){2}\s*=\s*\K\{([\d.]*)\}
```

And replace this with `\{\{\1\}\}`, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/90cc2e/2/).

---

Broken down, this says:

```
\w+            # at least one word character
\s*            # Zero or more spaces
(?:\[\d+\]){2} # [0][1] or any other two-dimensional array
\s*=\s*        # spaces = and spaces
\K             # "forget" everything
\{([\d.]*)\}   # match and capture {number}
```

Answer (score 2):

A Perl one-liner, cautious about literals such as `2u` and `1e-06l` (etc)

```
perl -pe's/(?:\[ [^]]+ \]){2} \s*=\s* \K (\{ [^}]+ \})/{$1}/x' in > out
```

The `(?:)` groups (without capture) and `(?:\[[^]]+\]){2}` is for `[n][m]`. The [`\K`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns) is the form of the [positive lookbehind](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind), which also drops previous matches so we don't have to put them back.

With an integer inside `[]` being just digits and with a float in `{}` being `n.m` this simplifies

```
perl -pe's/(?:\[\d+\]){2}\s*=\s*\K( \{[\d.]+\} )/{$1}/x' in > out
```

Note that `[\d.]` allows for all kinds of wrong things, like `.2..3`, but that is a different issue.

---

However, watch out for use of literals for numbers such as `2u` (with the suffix) which are fine as indices as well, along with `vec[1.2e+01]` or even `vec[1.2]`. The varied notation for float/double literals is also more likely to show up in data. Altogether I'd go with a more rounded pattern like

```
perl -pe's/(?:\[ [\d\w+-.]+ \]){2}\s*=\s*\K(\{ [\d\w+-.]+ \})/{$1}/x' in > out
```

Keep in mind that this allows various wrong formats and so it doesn't check data well.

Comment: And since we've got "tons of code", the [edit in-line switch (-i)](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/perl/3696/perl-one-liners/12740/edit-file-in-place#t=20170313080924884893) may prove handy in our case.

Comment: @DmitryEgorov Thank you, a good point.  That may well come handy.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach with sed:

```
sed -i -r 's/((\[[0-9]\]){2} *= )(\{[^}]*\})/\1{\3}/' file
```

and same in BRE mode :

```
sed -i 's/\(\(\[[0-9]\]\)\{2\} *= \({[^}]*}\)\)/\1{\2}/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i '/]\[/s/[{}]/&&/g' file
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.